# Legendre's Formula and its properties

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Legendre's Formula states that for any prime number p and any positive integer n, let $v_p(n!)$ be the exponent of the largest power of p that divides n. Then
$$v_p(n!) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \lfloor \frac{n}{p^i} \rfloor$$
I was looking at an article that used the fact that
$$v_p([n!]^2) = 2v_p(n!)$$
I also saw
$$v_p(\frac{[2n]!}{n!}) = v_p([2n]!) - v_p(n!) $$
However, I can't find a proof of this and I am not even sure how to go about proving this. This is really just for my own self studying.

Comment: See the argument of Vinogradov's in his Elementary Number Theory, beginning of chapter 2.

Comment: Yeah I looked through that book and I could not find anything about the properties. It just gave me the definition which I know.